# Apache isn't giving access to Kohana

Tags: php, apache, kohana, fedora

I can't access my app in apache. When I enter the url `localhost/my_app` in the browser it gives the error

> "You don't have permission to access /my_app on this server."

I am using fedora 20. 
My app is in the folder `/var/www/html`.

Thank you

Comment: What are the permissions on my_app?

Comment: i copied the kohana folder into /var/www/html folder and im trying to access index.php file . i havent done anything else yet

Comment: Do a `ls -l` and see what it says. Should be something like `-rw-r--r--` for your `index.php` file and `drwxr-xr-x` for your `my_app` directory.

Comment: for the index.php it is the same what you have mentioned and for my app it is total 64
total 64
drwx------.  9 root root 4096 Feb  9 23:17 application
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root root 9790 Jul 25  2016 build.xml
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root root   86 Jul 25  2016 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root root 7677 Jul 25  2016 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root root  517 Jul 25  2016 example.htaccess
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root root 3631 Jul 25  2016 index.php
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root root 8411 Jul 25  2016 install.php
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root root 1710 Jul 25  2016 LICENSE.md
drwxrwxrwx. 11 root root 4096 Mar 16  2016 mo

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the permissions on on the `my_app` folder to allow the world access to it:

```
chmod -R a+rx my_app
```